# Not unique table/alias: 'products'

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

Hi guys so this is my first time tackling inner join so any help greatly appreciated.

JUst wondering why I am getting the following error from the code I have created:

Not unique table/alias: 'products'

Here is the code itself:

```
mysql_select_db($database_reps, $reps);
$query_orders = sprintf("SELECT
orders.ID AS mainID,
customers.`Name` AS customerName,
products.ProductName AS product,
orders.Quantity AS Quantity,
orders.comment As comment,
orders.SalesPrice AS SalesPrice,
orders.Price AS Price,
orders.paid AS paid,
orders.product2 AS product2,
orders.AgeOfPayment AS AgeOfPayment,
orders.orderDate AS orderDate,
products.Price AS productPrice,
staff.StaffName AS staffMember,
orders.bonus AS bonus
FROM
orders
INNER JOIN staff AS staff ON orders.staffMember = staff.ID
INNER JOIN products AS products ON orders.product = products.ID
INNER JOIN products AS products ON orders.product2 = products.ID
INNER JOIN customers AS customers ON orders.customerName = customers.ID
WHERE
orders.ID = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_orders, "int"));

$orders = mysql_query($query_orders, $reps) or die(mysql_error());
$row_orders = mysql_fetch_assoc($orders);
$totalRows_orders = mysql_num_rows($orders);
```

Joins are proving a bit difficult but any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INNER JOIN products AS products ON orders.product = products.ID
INNER JOIN products AS products ON orders.product2 = products.ID
```

Both joins to the `products` table are being aliased as `products`, use different aliases for each like `products1` and `products2`; and make sure that you use the correct alias in your list of selected columns; though your select list doesn't really give any indication of which you want to reference

**EDIT**

```
SELECT orders.ID AS mainID,
       customers.`Name` AS customerName,
       products1.ProductName AS productName1,
       products2.ProductName AS productName2,
       orders.Quantity AS Quantity,
       orders.comment As comment,
       orders.SalesPrice AS SalesPrice,
       orders.Price AS Price,
       orders.paid AS paid,
       orders.product2 AS product2,
       orders.AgeOfPayment AS AgeOfPayment,
       orders.orderDate AS orderDate,
       products1.Price AS productPrice1,
       products2.Price AS productPrice2,
       staff.StaffName AS staffMember,
       orders.bonus AS bonus
  FROM orders
 INNER JOIN staff
    ON orders.staffMember = staff.ID
 INNER JOIN products AS products1 
    ON orders.product = products1.ID
 INNER JOIN products AS products2 
    ON orders.product2 = products2.ID
 INNER JOIN customers 
    ON orders.customerName = customers.ID
 WHERE orders.ID = ...
```

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for that. Im just a bit curious as to the layout. Can you give me an example of what you mean?

Comment: Which product name and price do you want to see in your selected column list? The name/price that matches orders.product, or that matches orders.product2? or both?

Comment: @ Strawberry I have changed it to the following: INNER JOIN products AS products ON orders.product = products.ID INNER JOIN products AS products2 ON orders.product2 = products.ID No errors coming back but i have this for example:

$product = $row_orders['product'];
$product2 = $row_orders['product2'];

When i echo out the product2, i get nothing

Comment: @MarkBaker Hi Mark, I inputted that edit, but when i do echo out $product2 I still get back just the ID of it. I have it listed like this:
`$product2 = $row_orders['product2'];`

Comment: Yes, `product2` will show you the id, because it's the `orders.product2` value... you need to look at $row_orders['productName1'] and $row_orders['productName2'] and $row_orders['productPrice1'] and $row_orders['productPrice2']

Comment: Ok you see the way you hav listed above `products1.ProductName AS productName1,` and `products2.ProductName AS productName2,`does that mean i need to create different tables such as products1 table and a products2 table?

Comment: No, you don't need different tables, that's the whole point of the alias. Both aliases reference the same table. The real question is what is `product` and `product2` in your orders table? Are these two different products that the customer has bought? Can they buy more than two products? In which case you should be normalize orders to include an order_lines table

Comment: `product`is the column in the orders table that when the customer orders something, the id is stored there from the `products`table. `product2` is another column in the orders table that drags information from the `products`table also and stores the id. Is there a different way that it should be done?

Comment: That doesn't really explain the purpose of the product2 reference, why it is needed! But what happens if a customer wants to order two or three different products?